# do - while with $var[x]

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

i'm still in the learning curve with php

I'm trying to achieve this:

let's say i have an ul with dynamically generated li's. And these li's must be populated with data stored in a variable. For example:

```
$var[0] = 'first data';
$var[1] = 'second data';
$var[2] = 'third data';
```

result:

```
<ul>
<li>first data</li>
<li>second data</li>
<li>third data</li>
</ul>
```

I know i must put something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php do { ?>
<li><?php echo $var ?></li>
<?php } while (condition); ?>
</ul>
```

But, i didn't figure which is the correct condition syntax, and how to create the variable which puts the differents items into the li's (the $var item into the li).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the PHP [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure to iterate through your array.

```
$var[0] = 'first data';
$var[1] = 'second data';
$var[2] = 'third data';

foreach ($var as $e) {
    echo "<li>{$e}</li>\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try that, it looks way more simpler than my approach! thanks a lot